# Circle in Google Sign-In approval emails

Tags: google-oauth

I am trying to keep an Google Sign In based application (which needs a few scopes like drive.install, drive.file, cloudprinting and spreadsheets) working.

This application (as well as the associated Google Sheets Add-On) has been approved  for years. Now Google wants justifications videos for the scopes (and for the consent screens).

I have provided them with the videos, but the approval process seems to circle in some rather meaningless emails I get every 2 days.

Google has now disabled new user registration. Is there a way of speeding this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, nearly a month (and 9 emails from me) later the request was granted by Google